# How to use CefSharp for WPF properly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, cefsharp

I created a new Wpf Project with VS2012. I right clicked on the Project and chose "Manage NuGet Packages". Then i installed the CefSharp Package for Wpf.

Then i used this "guide" : https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/README.WPF.md

Sadly i get like 4 Errors and i don't know how to get rid of them!

These are the errors i get (i took out the path to the project with "filepath"):

```
Error   5   The type 'cefSharp:WebView' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    "filepath"\Chromium\MainWindow.xaml 6   10  Chromium
Error   3   The name "WebView" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf".  "filepath"\Chromium\MainWindow.xaml 6   9   Chromium

Error   6   The name 'Cef' does not exist in the current context    "filepath"\Chromium\MainWindow.xaml.cs  28  13  Chromium
Error   4   Assembly 'CefSharp.Wpf' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built. "filepath"\Chromium\MainWindow.xaml 4   22  Chromium
```

My XAML for the MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="Chromium.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <cefSharp:WebView x:Name="WebView" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind for MainWindow.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using CefSharp;

namespace Chromium
{
    public partial class MainWindow 
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WebView.PropertyChanged += OnWebViewPropertyChanged;

            Cef.Initialize(new Settings());
        }

        private void OnWebViewPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "IsBrowserInitialized":
                    if (WebView.IsBrowserInitialized)
                    {
                        WebView.Load("http://10.211.55.2:42000");
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML and Code behind for the MainWindow are pretty much exactly the same as in the README.MD

I also copied over those 2 files (libcef.dll and icudt.dll) from the 0.25.7 Binary package from github to the bin\Debug and bin\Release folders by hand.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I got it down to 1 Error by setting the Target Framework to 4.0 and Platform target to x64. Still this error thought :

Error 3 The name "WebView" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf". "filepath"\Chromium\MainWindow.xaml 6 9 Chromium

Comment: Hmm, I realize this is a few months back and it *looks* like the guide and code you applied was for the CefSharp1 code branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I realize this is a few months back and it *looks* like the guide and code you applied was for the CefSharp1 code branch (that version did AFAIK only support x86). **Note** the WPF control for CefSharp1 and current `master` is quite different.

With CefSharp 33.0.0 just released I would suggest you try with that version of the NuGet *and* that you start out with getting everything running with the [WPF example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) of `CefSharp.MinimalExample` first. I think the guide you used has been changed a bit since then. Not sure if it's ready for prime time yet though.

Finally there's a recent post on the CefSharp Google Group with [a good write-up on the "DIY version of MinimalExample"](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cefsharp/cQ-zpHUQZn8/OVPAcyrb3SEJ). Read the first two posts there which I think should still apply.

Comment: Now *I* realize this is from a few months back, but I get the same problem using CefSharp 39.0.1 and the CefSharp.MinimalExample, as well as in my own code. But if I create the ChromiumWebBrowser manually in my .cs, it's fine. It's only when I (or MinimalExample) try to do it in the XAML that I get an error.

Comment: What error specifically are you getting? If it's `The name "XXXX" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"` can you get rid of it by closing the XAML file before starting debugging?

Comment: Ah, that indeed did get rid of it. It was never really stopping the build from happening, just erroneously claiming errors. Sorry, a bit new to this .NET stuff and still not used to "errors that aren't really errors" bit. :O

Comment: No, it's really confusing! I think https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Wpf_designer and the forum post it's linking to points to the possible underlying issue. If you can come up with a good phrase feel free to expand on the FAQ as it's a wiki page so editable to anyone with a GitHub account.